# Making a side bar using Flex Box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to use flex to make a side bar on the right side of the screen that is scroll-able underneath the hr. I have the columns set but for some reason the sidebar column appears underneath the main-content-column instead of the far right. The classes are "sidebar-column-right" and content-right . Im new to using flexbox so im probably doing something wrong.

```
<html>
            <head> 
                <title>Militia</title>
                <meta charset='utf-8'>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main-content.css">
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="container";>
                    <header> 
                        <ul class="left";> 
                            <li class="nav";><a class="a a-nav-top leftbuttons"; href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav";><a class="a a-nav-top leftbuttons"; href="#">Shop</a></li>
                            <li class="nav";><a class="logobutton"; href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmZOe6sv3wuq97Vo-9Rdyyw"; target="_blank";>RG</a></li>
                            <li class="nav";><a class="a a-nav-top rightbuttons"; href="#">Archives</a></li>
                            <li class="nav";><a class="a a-nav-top rightbuttons"; href="#">Suggestions</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </header>
                    <div class="home";>
                        <h1>Home</h1>
                        <p>Hello welcome to my site you guys know me already Recht A.K.A Domo. Here you can find my video upload schedule, previous video, current video, and you can make suggestions on what games I play.</p>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="main-content-column-left";>
                            <div class="content-left";>         
                                <h2>Previous Video (As of Jun-29-16):</h2>
                                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bDXMLKNPUGw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sale labore in mea. Eirmod deleniti probatus ne quo, nec cu graeci appellantur, latine denique usu ea. Pri   nonumes quaerendum cu. Tollit possim accommodare ei vel, ne augue ludus constituto sea. Mel summo scripta omittantur ad, cum ei zril quaeque definiebas.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content-left">
                                 <h3>Upload Schedule:</h3> 
                                <ol>
                                    <li id="schedule";>Mondays: Upload</li>
                                    <li id="schedule";>Tuesday: Upload</li>
                                    <li id="schedule";>Wendsday: Upload</li>
                                    <li id="schedule";>Thurday: Break</li>
                                    <li id="schedule";>Friday: Upload</li>
                                    <li id="schedule";>Saturday: Production</li>
                                    <li id="schedule";>Sunday: Production</li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="sidebar-column-right">
                            <div class="content-right";>
                                <h2>Im a side bar</h2>
                                <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

---

```
#container { /* added */
      width: 100%; /* adjust to your needs */
      max-width: 100%; /* responsive */
      margin: 0 ; /* horizontal centering */
      border: solid #DC143C;
      color: #DC143C;
    }



    .home{
      color: #DC143C;


    }


    .main-content-column-left{

      color: #DC143C;
      display: flex;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;

    }


    .sidebar-column-right{
      border-left: solid 1px;
      display: flex;
      color: #DC143C;
      border: solid 1px red;
      width: 33.3%;
      overflow-y: auto;


    }

    .content-left > iframe { /* added */
      width: 560px;
      height: 315px;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      color: #DC143C;



    }

    .content-left{
      color: #DC143C;
      width: 33%;



    }

    .content-right{



    }



    h1{
      color: #DC143C;
        text-align: center;
    }

    h2.previousvid
    {
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 20px; 
    }



    h3.sidecontent{
        text-align: right;
    }



    hr{
        border: 1px solid #DC143C;

    }

    ol {
      list-style-type: decimal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you are expecting. I added a div with `class = "flex-box"` above your `"sidebar-column-right"` and `content-right` classes and changed some css. Pls run the plunker code in the link.

https://plnkr.co/edit/L1aiT8SmNh9CosoaSnU6

Comment: yeah this is what i want but how would i make the side bar have its own scroll?

Comment: @Recht88 plunker code updated. Pls check if that is what you are expecting.

Comment: yeah that’s ehat I want but the side bars scroll only pops up when the screen is a certain size and not full.

Comment: could you pls specify the screen size for the side bar to get scrolled?

Comment: Regular desktop screen size

Comment: is it ok to use javascript or jquery to get the screen height?

Comment: Yeah it’s fine. However I’ve never used JavaScript and jquery before so you would have to explain how it works to me. If that’s possible.

Comment: @Recht88 sorry for the late response,,, i have updated the plunker. The explanation of code is given in script.js file. Thankx

Comment: Yes this worked very well thank you! Sorry for late reply haven't been able to sit down and respond